# How to run Mortal Kombat X on laptop with two video cards?

Tags: technical-issues, mortal-kombat-x

I have Intel Graphics and GT 540m. Apparently game at the start chooses integrated graphic card and message pops out "Your video card or drivers do not meet minimum system requirements". 
I set global parameter in Nvidia control settings to be GT540. I've set same specifically for this game, but it keeps checking at the start integrated graphic card.
How to solve it?

Comment: Are you just assuming its looking at the Intel Graphics? Or does it actually say that, apart from "does not meet requirements"? Have you updated your drivers? I did a quick check on the minimum requirements, and while your card should technically work, benchmark tests actually place it under the minimum card Mortal Kombat X requires.

Comment: Yeah, it is a guess. Based on facts that it is DirectX Error, and Direct X diagnostic tool(dxdiag) shows only integrated adapter. And there is youtube video that show MKX running on GT540m. I tried update drivers, it didn't helped.

Comment: try to use device manager to disable Intel Graphics card , reboot and try to play , that should force using your Nvidia card ,, I don't know much with dual graphics card systems , but this is just my theory , do it at your own risk :P